# Explanation required for BITCOUNT macro

Tags: c++, c, macros

Can someone explain how this works?

```
#define  BX_(x)         ((x) - (((x)>>1)&0x77777777)                    \
                             - (((x)>>2)&0x33333333)                    \
                             - (((x)>>3)&0x11111111))


#define BITCOUNT(x)     (((BX_(x)+(BX_(x)>>4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F) % 255)
```

### Clarification:

Ideally, the answer will start something along the lines of:

The macro: "BX_" subtracts three values from the passed in number.

These three values represent:

1. XXXXX
2. YYYYY
3. ZZZZZ

This allows the BITCOUNT() to work as follows...

Cheers,

David

Comment: Have you picked your favorite 8-digit hex number and run the macro by hand to see what comes out?  If not, try that.

Comment: Yes - and it works - for the small sample of numbers I've tried. I just want a brief explanation on how the macro works.

Comment: I think when John says "run the macro by hand", he means "use a calculator or a pencil and paper to work out each step of the macro in turn, and look at the intermediate values to see how it works". A quicker way of doing the same might be to re-write the macro as a function, break the expressions into lots of lines doing one thing each, and single-step it.

Comment: I just want someone to tell me how it works - not describe to me a method by which I can figure out the answer myself. I'd prefer to work backwards from the brief explanation rather than forwards using a recommended method.

Comment: @ephemient: I've heard bad rumours that `__builtin_popcount` is "worse" (in particular slower) than various bit-twiddling hacks on x86, although I've never needed to check for myself.

Comment: I took my own advice and tried it out.  I posted an answer below.

Comment: "just want someone to tell me how it works - not describe to me a method by which I can figure out the answer myself." Huh? You'd rather have to be spoon-fed every idea you want to understand rather than be able to figure them out on your own?

Comment: No - I'd rather the question I ask answered, not have the answerer make assumptions on what's best for me.

Comment: What's best for you is to have a better grasp on understanding problems, not be intellectually lazy and never learn more than how to ask someone else.

Comment: @GMan: no need to be a jerk about it, though. If I ask, "how does an optical mouse work?" do you talk about light scattering off the surface of my desk, or do you tell me to stop being so lazy, dismantle my mouse and figure it out for myself?

Comment: I don't think I was being a jerk at all. Your analogy is false.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The output of BX_(x) is the number of on bits in each hex digit.  So

```
BX_(0x0123457F) = 0x01121234
```

The following:

```
((BX_(x)+(BX_(x)>>4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F)
```

shuffles the counts into bytes:

```
((BX_(0x0123457F)+(BX_(0x0123457F)>>4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F) = 0x01030307
```

Taking this result modulo 255 adds up the individual bytes to arrive at the correct answer 14.  To see that this works, consider just a two-byte integer, 256*X + Y.  This is just 255*X + X + Y, and 255*X % 255 is always zero, so

```
(256*X + Y) % 255 = (X + Y) % 255.
```

This extends to four-byte integers:

256^3*V + 256^2*W + 256*X + Y

Just replace each 256 with (255+1) to see that

```
(256^3*V + 256^2*W + 256*X + Y) % 255 = (V + W + X + Y) % 255.
```

The final observation (which I swept under the rug with the 2-digit example) is that `V + W + X + Y` is always less than 255, so

```
(V + W + X + Y) % 255 = V + W + X + Y.
```

Answer (score 1):

As quoted by Johannes from that splendid [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) page, there's an excellent and detailed description of that algorithm in [Software Optimization Guide for AMD Athlon™ 64 and Opteron™ Processors](http://www.amd.com/us-en/assets/content_type/white_papers_and_tech_docs/25112.PDF) from AMD on page numbers 179 and 180 - corresponding to pages 195 and 196 of the PDF.

Also describing the same idea and some alternative solutions and their relative performance: [this page](http://gurmeetsingh.wordpress.com/2008/08/05/fast-bit-counting-routines/).